# Generar archivos .part.zip client-side

Tags: javascript, jszip

Estoy lidiando con la generación de archivos .zip de a partes.

Actualmente estoy utilizando JSZip para meter los archivos pero no encuentro forma de que los genere partidos (.zip.000, .zip.001...).

Solo puedo generar un único archivo

¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?